# Failed to load viewstate error after moving website to a new server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I don't really know where to start with this one. I am getting:

```
`Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.`
```

after moving a website to a new server. The exact same code works on my other server. It happens when I submit one of my forms (but doesn't do it on all form submissions).

Any ideas what can cause this so I have somewhere to look?

Using: ASP.NET 2.

EDIT: I am adding some user controls to a placeholder dynamically at runtime but this same code is working ok on my other server. I have tried clearing the controls in the place holder before adding new ones (as I saw a post about that) but it hasn't helped.

EDIT2: It seems that the postback is just failing. It isn't going into the onClick code of the button either so something is deffintiely screwy .. If I try / catch the exception it seems that all the controls are still added successfully ... Setting my Dynamic UC's to EnableViewState = false resolves this particular error.

EDIT3: Ok, I think I may have a handle on what is happening. For some reason on the old server the form action is `default.aspx?action=amend` but the new server is showing `amend.html?action=amend` so I think the re-write module is messing up in IIS. This would explain the control adding issue as well because the action is happening 2 times (I think). I will look into the Rewrite module and see if anything is wrong then post back.

Comment: Both servers have the same version of .NET? I've found some cases on the internet, when it was caused by some compatibility problems .net2 vs .net3.5, so maybe it's worth to check.

Comment: Yes, both servers have the same version unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried to identify the control which is causing this? Are you dynamically adding some controls?

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look at these articles:

http://blog.typps.com/2008/01/failed-to-load-viewstate-typical.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/guys/archive/2004/12/05/275321.aspx

Or try a simple temporary solution - disable viewstate for this placeholder. Either way, I'm puzzled why it actually works on your first server. I'd be glad if someone else will be able to clarify this subject more.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the post back Url for the form is wrong on this server (unsure why at the moment, I will update when I know). This is causing the dynamic controls to be added in an unexpected way and causing the error. I noticed this when I managed to post my form and the content didn't update. I manually adjusted the action url using firebug and all is well.

Worth looking at walther's answer regarding dynamic controls and the viewstate though.

Not sure what caused it but I am manually setting the form action in the page load now and it seems to have solved the issue.